# How to estimate file size from pixel dimensions using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using the Python library PIL to create a solid black PNG, but am confused by the file size. With an 8-bit pixel depth, I would expect that a 1000x1000 pixel square to be a 1MB file. However, when I run the code below I get a file that is 2.89KB or 4KB on disk. Why is this? How could I estimate the size of a file given the pixel dimensions?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as image

file = "/images/test.png"
width = 1000
height = 1000

img = np.zeros([width,height],dtype=np.uint8)
img.fill(0)

data = image.fromarray(img, mode="L") 
data.save(file)
```

Comment: Thr file is stored in a compressed state to make it smaller.

Comment: PNG is compressed (losslessly).  Why do you need to guess by how much in advance?

Comment: Lossless, this does not mean it is uncompressed. You can probably get the compression details and the size and dimensions from the image metatdata.

Answer (score 1):

By default when saving a PNG, Pillow will use a compression level of 6 (an arbitrary value).

You can change this behaviour by using the named arg compress_level, which ranges from 0 (no compression) to 9 (maximum compression). Playing with that, you should correctly observe wildly varying sizes !

Try `data.save(file, compress_level=0)` for example

Link to pillow docs for extra info : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png-saving

That being said, your endeavor of guessing in advance the file size is not really feasible except using a compress_level of 0, but that has its own problems...